# NOOVERRIDE=1 not working in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, nooverride

I overrided the view button of my Custom Object to a VF page. Now the VF page is not ready for Lightning Experience, so I want to redirect my users to the standard/lightning page layout.

In Salesforce classic, I know I can use nooverride=1, but doesn't seem to work in Lightning. I tried to play with sforce.one.navigateToUrl but same result. I also tried to use navigateToSObject, but it just keep looping (because the view button is overriden by the VF page, which make sense actually).

I notice Salesforce transforms my ***/a5S90000000Gpxl?nooverride=1*** to something like : 
***xxxx.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/a5S90000000Gpxl/nooverride/view?t=1461032202945***

with the following error message:***This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or Salesforce1.***

What am I missing ?

Comment: I have not tried the `nooverride` trick in lightning yet, but if you want your page available in LEX go to `Setup -> Develop -> VF Pages` and enable `Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages` for your page

Comment: my VF page that is calling the noverride is already available for Lightning yes. It's the nooverride that is not working, which is supposed to be the standard page layout. Would that be something that is not supported by Lightning yet ?

Comment: Page overrides are done a bit different in LEX. As of Srping '16 there is a Record Page template available in the Lightning App Builder that allows you to override a standard record page. It's still beta at this point in time but that's something that you should be looking at.

Comment: Raised a case to salesforce to see what they recommend. Let's see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this might help someone. Salesforce Support confirmed that nooverride=1 is not supported in lightning experience

> Unfortunately, this does not work in Lightning experience. I have
>   confirmed this within my Team as well in order to confirm the same.
>
> Also, you can post an idea for the same on Ideaexchange so that it can
>   be considered in future release if there will be other customers as
>   well who want the same feature.

If anyone is interested to make this happen, I invite you to vote for this idea on [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lDIFQA2).

**UPDATE 15-09-2016:** Fixed in winter 17. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a serious shortcoming of LEX in my opinion. The "Dispatcher Page" pattern in visualforce is quite common. This is where you override with a visualforce page that runs some apex to determine where (whether custom page or standard layout) to send the user. This dispatcher logic can be as complex as needed. It is currently utterly impossible to send a user to a standard page once it has been overridden. We don't need url hacks to achieve this, just a simple api method in the sforce.one.navigation apis.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in Winter 17. Can somehow confirm this ?

Comment: Someone commented two days ago on the Idea you linked that it was *not* fixed in `Winter 17`.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I added couple of screenshot to my answers, just retested now. Seems ok to me

Comment: @CloudNinja - Can you provide details of the format you used for the NoOverride to work? I'm trying it with navigateToURL and I'm not seeing this work. With thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is working in Lightning Experience

https://XXXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Contact/CONTACTID/view?nooverride=1

Comment: I can confirm nooverride = 1 works again